# Linux webcam recorder

Tags: linux, webcam

On Windows there are several programs to record video+audio from your webcam (many just come with the webcam), but I would like one for linux.  I haven't been able to find anything for linux... any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use "cheese" with Ubuntu.

Comment: wow... I didn't realize there was a video feature for cheese. Thanks!